# @media width and font size

Tags: html, css

I have a simple bit of CSS used to resize text if the page width drops to below 768 px:

```
<style type="text/css">
.rand1 {
  font: 20px/0.5 'Volkhov', serif;;
}


@media (min-width: 768px)
{
    .rand1 {
      font: 50px/1.3 'Volkhov', serif;;
    }
}                   

</style>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Volkhov' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

It works fine - e.g. you can see it on a sample page here:

http://jimpix.co.uk/words/username-generator.asp?yours=Joy&go=yes&ul1=0&dt=d2

The thing that confuses me is that when the page is full width / wider than 768 px, it uses the 50px font size, and when narrower, it uses the 20px, smaller font size.

I'd have thought it'd be the other way round - e.g. if the page is narrower than 768 px, it'd use the CSS in the @media section of the CSS - but it seems to be the other way round.

Am I just being dim?

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can't see the cunfusion. You tell in CSS that if the page is at least 768px wide, it shall use font 50px. Else it shall use 20px. So basically you overwrite the rand1 when size is more than 768px.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using min-width instead of max-width. So you say, If the page is wider than 768px make the font-size 50px.

If you change your code to:

```
.rand1 {
  font: 50px/1.3 'Volkhov', serif;;
}


@media (max-width: 768px)
{
    .rand1 {
      font: 20px/0.5 'Volkhov', serif;;
    }
}
```

It will do what you thought it would do.
Hope I explained right.

http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/